# Getting all elements in a page with specific span class python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, html-table

Hi I am attempting to scrape multiple pages using selenium in python. I am interested in extracting all elements that fall within a span class element, basically what I would like to do is get the span class elements then extract the link within it. For each page it is possible to achieve this by using the xpath, however the xpath changes for each object and for each page. here is an example of what the web elements look like:

[image]

essentially I would like to extract the  elements this is consistent in all the pages that I will be scraping. SO my idea is to get these elements then to get the href elements for these. I have tried to get all the elements on the page using this code

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='Text__StyledText-jknly0-0 cCEhaW']")
```

However this has not worked and it returns nothing. I also do not want to use the inner class because it varies by page as well so the only real element to use if I want to automate the scraping without getting too messy is that element I mention. Any way to extract the links for this span class elements on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this xpath

```
//span[contains(@class,'Text__StyledText')]//a[contains(@class,'Anchor__StyledAnchor')]
```

Answer (score 0):

To actually grab that element we use the following

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.Text__StyledText-jknly0-0.cCEhaW")
```

Comment: Hi I am working in python. This is returning an empty list, so it does not work.

Comment: Is the class changing everytime?

Comment: What website is it from?